# Trying to change json (gltf) and save it with php

Tags: php, json, gltf

i'm trying to change gltf'S texture with php;

```
$jsonString = file_get_contents('jsonFile.gltf');
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);

foreach ($data as $key => $entry) {
    if ($entry['uri'] == 'textures/CARA_A_baseColor.jpeg') {
        $data[$key]['uri'] = "textures/Another_baseColor.jpeg";
    }
}

$newJsonString = json_encode($data);
file_put_contents('jsonFile.gltf', $newJsonString);
echo "bitti";
```

and here is the code what i want to change;

```
"images": [
    {
      "uri": "textures/CARA_A_baseColor.jpeg"
    },
    {
      "uri": "textures/CARA_B_baseColor.jpeg"
    },
    {
      "uri": "textures/GLASS_normal.jpeg"
    }
  ],
```

i want to change first child (textures/CARA_A_baseColor.jpeg) with new value (textures/Another_baseColor.jpeg) and save it again. Can anybody help me to understand that how can i select first child of "images" and change it. Ty.

Comment: Your code seems reasonable. I think the problem is that the "images" are nested much deeper in the JSON than your question let us believe. The first question therefore should be: How do you get to the "images" array. We can't help you there, because we don't know the content of your JSON file. Perhaps someone who is familiar with these gltf files will know?

Comment: This probably requires digging around in the [glTF™ 2.0 Specifications](https://registry.khronos.org/glTF/specs/2.0/glTF-2.0.html). The "images" can be found in [A.17. JSON Schema for glTF](https://registry.khronos.org/glTF/specs/2.0/glTF-2.0.html#schema-reference-gltf).

Answer (score -1):

```
$jsonString = file_get_contents('jsonFile.gltf');
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);

$data['images'][0]['uri'] = "textures/Another_baseColor.jpeg";

$newJsonString = json_encode($data);
file_put_contents('jsonFile.gltf', $newJsonString);
echo "bitti";
```

I solved my problem with the code above, thank you